# Does C always initialize the last element in char array to zero?

Tags: c, gcc

By running this code

```
char array[6];
int i;
for ( i = 0; i < 6; ++i )
    printf("%i ", array[i]);
```

Possible output:

```
64 0 -64 77 67 0
```

I get **always** the last element 0, although I was expecting random value. It is compiler dependent? I'm using gcc.

Comment: You don't get _random_ numbers, but you get _indeterminate_ numbers.

Comment: The simple  answer - No

Comment: Curious - _always the last element 0_.    How many times is _always_ ?

Comment: @ryyker I get **always** last element 0, no matter if I run this code 10 or 10000 times, no matter if the array has size 5 or 5000

Comment: Due to the automatic storage of your array, probably, the code before the function where the code is placed, leave that 0 into the stack.

Comment: @Tom don't waste anymore time on this, or step through the assymbly code with a debugger if you want to know what exactly happens in your case.

Comment: I would be curious to know what would happen if you completely closed your environment between compiles.  I have observed behaviors where something that should be randomly changing does not change between compiles. But closing Code::Blocks, which also uses GCC compiler, (i.e., dumping it from memory) then re-opening, I see that the value changes from what it was during the compilers previous life.

Comment: @ryyker I have completely closed my environtment and then tried building, rebuilding, closing again, rebuilding but still the same result :) I'am also using Code::Blocks.

Comment: @Tom - I am not sure if the question's _duplicate_ status prevents it, but selecting one of the answers as _Accepted_ is always appreciated.

Comment: @rykker Yes I know and I will do it, but I have not decided yet which one ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. There's no such thing guaranteed by the C standard for local variables.

The values of the uninitialized array has *indeterminate values*. So, you can't access them and since you do, your code has *undefined behaviour*.

But the variables with static storage duration such as global variables, `static` qualified variables etc are initialized with zero.

Comment: Hmmm.  _...So, you can't access them..._.  Should that be _...you should not access them..._?

Comment: Strictly speaking *you must not access them* is the most accurate ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The contents of a variable (and by extension, the elements of an array) that do not have static storage duration (globals, `static` locals) are undefined.

The fact that the last element in the array happens to be 0 essentially *is* random.

Answer (score 3):

Last element is zero in string constants like `"Test"` or `char array[] = "Test";`. In your example last value is zero by chance.

Try this:

```
void f1() // prepare non-zero stack
{
  char array[40];

  memset( array, 32, sizeof array ); 
}

void f2() // your array
{
  char array[6];
  int i;
  for ( i = 0; i < 6; ++i )
    printf("%i ", array[i]);
}

int main()
{
  f1();
  f2();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: OP includes statement: _I get always the last element 0_.  If this is an accurate observation (as opposed to an exaggeration) then _by chance_ may not be accurate.

Comment: @ryyker It is by chance. I can show example how to get value other than 0. (Has to fill the stack before calling such function.) And the question is "Does C always initialize...", not "is this in my case".

Comment: @i486 I would be grateful to see this example, can you show it please?

Comment: @Tom Try example in the answer above.

Comment: @i486 You have right, now I don't get 0 anymore, Thanks!